# how to fit run time permission in MIUI

Tags: android, runtime-permissions

I used android api for run time permission,but it didnot worked in XIAOMI MIUI。it always return 0 when i requestPermission.

Comment: please show your code

Comment: post your code..

Comment: `if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission) != 
       PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return true;
            }else{ return false}`
I refused permission but it returns fase

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer.

If your application is targeting an API level before 23 (Android M) then both:ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission and Context.checkSelfPermission doesn't work and always returns 0 (PERMISSION_GRANTED). Even if you run the application on Android 6.0 (API 23).

The solution:
As I said in the 1st point, if you targeting an API level before 23 on Android 6.0 then ContextCompat.CheckSelfPermission and Context.checkSelfPermission doesn't work. Fortunately you can use PermissionChecker.checkSelfPermission to check run-time permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I Had no problem with runtime permission on my Xiaomi MI3 with MIUI, are you sure to ask runtime permission correctly?

post you code or follow this guide:  https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: I had followed this guid and it no problem worded in other phone  

There is an option like  **Notify** in MIUI  Permission manager,i choosed it . 

MIUI popuped a RequestPermisssionDialog but i refused the permission. 
**ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission)** will alaws return **PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED**

Answer (score 0):

ok,i fixed this problem.

I used

`PermissionChecker.checkPermission(this, permission, Process.myPid(),Process.myUid()`

replace

`ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, permission)`